# geometry symmedian problem EGMO 4.29

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let ABC be a triangle. The tangents of (ABC) from B and C meet at X. AX meet (ABC) at K. Show that BC is the B-symmedian of $\bigtriangleup ABK$ and the C-symmedian of $ \bigtriangleup ACK.$

This problem is from the book Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads from Evan Chen (Problem 4.29).
I tried to use that ABK is similar to AMC where M is the midpoint of BC. And I also define the isogonal of BD and tried to prove that it is the midpoint. The book says that with the property $\frac{AB}{BK}=\frac{AC}{CK}$ it can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and let $A'$ be reflection of $A$ with respect to $M$, so $ABA'C$ is a parallelogram and $AA'$ is the $A$ median of $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

it is well known that $X$ and $A'$ are isogonal conjugates of each other.

Let $K$ be $AX \cap (ABC) \neq A$.

Let's prove that the tangent lines to $(ABC)$ on $A$ and $K$ meet up on line $BC$: for let $Y$ be the meeting of those two tangents, then line $AK$ is the polar of $Y$ and so we can conclude that $X$ is in the polar of $Y$. By La Hire's theorem, we have that $Y$ is in the polar of $X$ which is the line $BC$. Therefore, $Y,B$ and $C$ are collinear.

We are done, because from my very image which proves that $AX$ is the symmedian of $\triangle ABC$ we must have also that $CY$ is the symmedian of $\triangle ABK$.

Comment: The thing to prove is that BC is the B-Symmedian of ABK and C the C-Symmedian of ACK, not AX A-Symmedian of ABC. But we can use the fact that AX is the A-Symmedian.

Comment: oh, of course, sorry

Comment: @alexgsi is it good now or do you want some extra calculations and definitions?

Comment: yes please, the property that you mention "only points Ki in ω that make the quadrilateral ABCKi harmonic are the meetings of the three symmedians of △ABC on ω. " is what I want to proof.

Comment: ok, are you used with poles and polars?

Comment: no, but I can search what they are. Also in the book says that what I mentioned about similar triangles and define the isogonal is enough to prove the problem. Another property that it mentions is $\frac{AB}{BK}=\frac{AC}{CK}$.

Comment: @alexgsi that hint that the book gave you is the worst definition of harmonic quadrilateral they could use to prove the facts that you want to prove (the product of opposite sides being equal). Please look up for the concept of poles and polars and for a demonstration of La Hire's theorem https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/LaHire.shtml#:~:text=Proof&text=OA%C2%B7OD%20%3D%20OB%C2%B7OC,A%2C%20and%20B%20are%20collinear.

Comment: ok, I will read about it.

Comment: @alexgsi I proved the claim you wanted me to prove. You may want to dig in the theory of poles and polars before you read my answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hcir5da8Tk

Comment: ok, thank you!!